# Creating a table in an external SQL Server

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

In LightSwitch, is there anyway to create a table in an external SQL Server database, rather than in the local ApplicationData data source ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the deployment options ... if you create a "local" LightSwitch table, rather than connect to an external data source. Then when you go through the Deployment Wizard, there is a "Database Connections" page. On this you can "Specify administrator connection for new or existing databases". The "local" table is created in that database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attach to an external Data Source functionality. If you have VS 2010 Pro or above you can use that to create the tables in the separate DB. Then just follow the wizard within LightSwitch to connect to it. If you don't have VS 2010 there are several SQL Server compatible query tools that you could use.

[MS SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593)